# How can i populate the values in a related list i.e Schedule of an opportunity line item

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

[image]I have an opportunity object ,with the related list as products.We do have different products with their sales price ,quantity ,list price etc.Now when i click on one of the product name ,it takes me to the product page.In that page we do have Schedule as a related list with their date column ,quantity etc.Now i would like to Dynamically populate the value of pricing request instead of date column.How to achieve this.Any help is very much appreciated.

Eg: Opportunity-->products---productname-->Schedule-->Datecolumn --->remove datecolumn and dynamically populate the value of  pricing request and quantity.

Created a custom object as Opportunity line item -- With the fields  part numbers as with some picklist value , the pricing request  with the quarter nos and the quantity and price.I Should relate this custom object to opportunity page or to the opportunity line item . Created a Vf Page .

Now how can i populate the vf page in the Schedule list by removing the Date field and how does the values get saved. Any suggestion ?

Here is my page :

```
<apex:page standardController="OpportunityLineItem__c"  sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageblockSection title="Schedule"> 
<apex:inputField value="{!OpportunityLineItem__c.ProductPartNumbers__c}"/>  
<apex:inputField value="{!OpportunityLineItem__c.PricingRequestsQuarterNos__c}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!OpportunityLineItem__c.Quantity__c}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!OpportunityLineItem__c.Price__c}"/>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: We can't see you VF page here.Please update your post with the page code.

Comment: Where is the datecolumn here??
Your requirement is still not clear.

Comment: @sales_lion:PFA ScreenShot of a detailed page of an opportunity product and the related list as Schedule.Now i need to populate the value as Pricing request and part numbers by removing the date column or By adding an VF Page to the related list.